# Why isn't canned food good forever?

Tags: food-chemistry

So everything inside the can has been killed and nothing can get in. So why doesn't it last forever then?

Comment: https://www.today.com/food/when-do-canned-foods-really-expire-t119977

Comment: This is a good and interesting question! But this is probably the wrong site for it. It might be on-topic in [Biology SE](https://biology.stackexchange.com/) or [Cooking SE](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/) and somewhat surprisingly in [Space Exploration SE](https://space.stackexchange.com/) where there is a keen interest on keeping prepared food appetizing and delicious for months and in the future for years!

Comment: Not an answer, but food is full of all kinds of chemicals and they can interact with each other, and simply degrade over time. It doesn't become "gone bad" from bacteria, it does it all by itself.

Comment: Canned food slowly approaches its chemical equilibrium with itself and the walls, what state may not be as attractive,  tasty and healthy as the original state.

Comment: Why do you think nothing gets in? All things leak, the only question is how fast…

Comment: Consider that molecules can degrade themselves. You do not need food, as every chemist knows. It is just matter of time. If you are concerned with bacteriological danger, a well sealed beans can likely last as long as the can do. But that doesn't mean that the nutritional value or the palatability of the beans do not decay at all.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

TL;DR Corrosion is the main culprit. USDA says low acidity canned foods may last up to 5 years, high acidity up to a year, because cans corrode with time, especially at higher temperatures.

An answer to this could range from the trivially philosophical ("nothing lasts forever") to challenging the premises of the question (who says everything has been killed/spores/nothing needs to get in because oxygen and water/does lasting mean being edible?).

It is however interesting that foods can be treated and packaged to retain near to original properties after extended time, and why this time can vary. The US Department of Agriculture -- in what would seem to be unnecessary exposure to potential lawsuits -- states on its official [website](https://www.usda.gov/media/blog/2013/06/27/you-toss-food-wait-check-it-out):

> Most **shelf-stable** foods are safe **indefinitely**. In fact, canned goods will last for years, as long as the can itself is in good condition (no rust, dents, or swelling). Packaged foods (cereal, pasta, cookies) will be safe past the ‘best by’ date, although they may eventually become stale or develop an off flavor. You’ll know when you open the package if the food has lost quality. Many dates on foods refer to quality, not safety. See FSIS’ Shelf-Stable Food Safety fact sheet for more information.

Avoiding the question of what is "shelf-stable", which sounds like a circular and not very useful definition (it is when it is), one can click on from the above website and come across further information from the [USDA](https://www.fsis.usda.gov/food-safety/safe-food-handling-and-preparation/food-safety-basics/shelf-stable-food):

> **Will commercially canned foods last forever?**
> Commercial canning is done under tightly controlled conditions — careful sanitation and the necessary time and temperature under pressure, but there are still limits to how long it will preserve food. There are several factors that limit the shelf life of canned foods. First, cans can rust over time. Shipping accidents, where cans fall and dent or are crushed, also cause container problems.
> Then there's can corrosion. In all foods, but especially in high-acid foods like canned tomatoes, natural chemicals in the food continually react with the container. Over several years, this can cause taste and texture changes, and eventually lower the nutritional value of the food.
> High temperatures (over 100 °F) are harmful to canned goods too. The risk of spoilage jumps sharply as storage temperatures rise. In fact, canned goods designed for use in the tropics are specially manufactured.
> Store canned foods and other shelf stable products in a cool, dry place. Never put them above or beside the stove, under the sink, in a damp garage or basement, or any place exposed to high or low temperature extremes. Temperatures below 85 °F are best. Check your pantry every few weeks and use canned goods you have had on hand for awhile. Don't purchase bulging, rusted, leaking, or deeply dented cans.

That still seems an incomplete answer. Assuming the can retains its original shape and does not rust, will the food inside last forever? What about the expiration dates, what are those for? On that the above site [states](https://www.fsis.usda.gov/food-safety/safe-food-handling-and-preparation/food-safety-basics/shelf-stable-food):

> Except for infant formula and some baby food, product dating — having a "use-by," "sell-by," or "best-if-used-by" date — is not required by Federal regulations. Dating is for quality, not safety. However, if a calendar date is used, it must express both the month and day of the month (and the year, in the case of shelf-stable and frozen products). If a calendar date is shown, immediately adjacent to the date must be a phrase explaining the meaning of that date, such as "sell by" or "use before." While there is no uniform or universally accepted system used for food dating in the United States, dating of some foods is required by more than 20 states. A shelf-stable product can be safely used after the "sell-by" date. Products displaying a "use-by" date, although still safe, **may not be of acceptable quality** after the "use-by" date.

Quality means that the contents have chemically degraded resulting in loss of textural properties, nutritional value, or flavor. It does not (necessarily) mean that it is unsafe.

Comment: I refer here to commercial canned food.